# How to conform <textarea> to multi-column layout?

Tags: html, forms, css, frontend

This will display some text in columns:

```
<div class="content-box" style="column-width: 8em">
  <p>blah blah...</p>
  <p>blah blah...</p>
  <p>blah blah...</p>
</div>
```

However, textarea does not seem to wrap column-wise like the rest of the text:

```
<div class="content-box" style="column-width: 8em">
  <p>blah blah...</p>
  <textarea rows="100"></textarea>
  <p>blah blah...</p>
  <p>blah blah...</p>
</div>
```

I want to display a textarea in line with the text that, if it's too long, will spill into the next column. It should basically look like the text except it is an editable area.  Is there a way to make this work?

I'm trying to build a mad-libs application. There is a multi-column layout of text (looks like a newspaper) except certain parts of the text should be editable (fill-in-the-blank areas). Editable areas may be long and should spill gracefully into the next column if they happen to run into the end of one, just like normal text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `textarea` will not do that, but a `contenteditable` element will

```css
div[contenteditable] {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-box" style="column-width: 8em">
  <p>blah blah...</p>
  <div contenteditable>
  blah edit<br>
  blah edit<br>
  blah edit<br>
  blah edit<br>
  blah edit<br>
  blah edit<br>
  blah edit<br>
  blah edit<br>
  blah edit<br>
  blah edit<br>
  blah edit<br>
  </div>
  <p>blah blah...</p>
  <p>blah blah...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Beware that there are much more implicit behaviors implied with `contenteditable` than what is allowed in a `textarea`. The user may input (or copy/paste) some HTML content which will lead to unpredicted results if not anticipated. Moreover, if you are interested in retreiving the value for processing, you still need to either process events or find a way to convert the HTML content back to text or default to the `textContent` and cross fingers. If all defaults suit your case, this is the way to go though.

Comment: @Simon Thanks for your comment. I am very well aware of that. Anyone who start using `contenteditable` are not in an immediate danger, it is when you allow someone to post data to your web server you need to know what to do, and when, whether one use a `contenteditable` or a `textarea`, the danger is equally big...and the question was about how to flow an editable text column wise.

Comment: Of course, my comment was for general information if anyone else comes to see this answer

Answer (score -1):

I do not think you can acheive this using a `textarea` element. This is dependent on the browser defaults and does not allow as much flexibility as other elements.

What you can do is to simulate a sort of textarea via CSS and handle the events yourself (using keyboard and mouse events). Though this may be a lot of work.